# How to use intent in android, i have 2 working programs, cannot combine

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, sms, send

I have to send my gps coordinates via SMS, firstly I made the SMS sender program, it is working. After that I found a code for my GPS coordinates, it is working too. I have to connect this codes. when i click the button, it must send SMS,
I tried it with intent, but there are a problem. when i click the button, the program stop and close..

here is my activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/choice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="coarse accuracy selected (default)"
    android:layout_below='@+id/fineAccuracy'
    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/fineAccuracy"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="fine accuracy"
    android:layout_below='@+id/chooseRadio'

    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/chooseRadio"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_below='@+id/prov'
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prov"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No provider selected yet"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below='@+id/lat'
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Latitude: -"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lon"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Longitude: -"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="11"
    android:id="@+id/telNo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/choice"
    android:hint="Telefon Numarasını Giriniz."
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Konumunu SMS Gönder"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/telNo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />
```

Comment: here is MainActivity.java

Comment: send .java code and logcat output

Comment: i send .java code and logcat, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.oguz.gpssms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView latitude;
    private TextView longitude;
    private TextView choice;
    private CheckBox fineAcc;
    private Button choose;
    private TextView provText;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private MyLocationListener mylistener;
    private Criteria criteria;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
        longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lon);
        provText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prov);
        choice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice);
        fineAcc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fineAccuracy);
        choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseRadio);
        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the location provider
        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE); //default
        // user defines the criteria
        choose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(fineAcc.isChecked()){
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                    choice.setText("fine accuracy selected");
                }else {
                    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                    choice.setText("coarse accuracy selected");
                }
            }
        });
        criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
        // get the best provider depending on the criteria
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        // the last known location of this provider
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        mylistener = new MyLocationListener();
        if (location != null) {
            mylistener.onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            // leads to the settings because there is no last known location
     //       Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
     //       startActivity(intent);
        }
        // location updates: at least 1 meter and 200millsecs change
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 200, 1, mylistener);
    }
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Initialize the location fields
            latitude.setText("Latitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            longitude.setText("Longitude: "+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            provText.setText(provider + " provider has been selected.");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  "Location changed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, provider + "'s status changed to "+status +"!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider " + provider + " enabled!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider " + provider + " disabled!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the SmsActivity.java

```
package com.example.oguz.gpssms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by OGUZ on 26.12.2014.
 */
public class SmsActivity extends MainActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.telNo);

        final String telNo = editText.getText().toString();
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" +telNo);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body","Merhaba");
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        });

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare your SmsActivity class in Androidmanifest file, and onclick of button1 pass this 2 variables latitude and longitude to SmsActivity. Read online documents how to pass data between activity and how to add activity in manifest

Comment: it is working now, 
 intent.putExtra("sms_body","Merhaba");
,,,,,,,i have to write the lon and lat values instead of "Merhaba"..
how can i make it?